# Function handler GoLang using Standard Library

Tags: go, gorilla, mux, url-parsing

I have an endpoint like `events/{id}` and a handler for it. How can I get `{id}` without using Gorilla/Mux. What are the GoLang in-built alternatives that can achieve this? Need to do this without gorilla/Mux or other third-party libraries. I know this can be done with mux.Vars but can't use it here.

Comment: id := strings.TrimPrefix(req.URL.Path, "/events/")

Answer (score 2):

If you already managed to direct the traffic to your handler, then you can simply parse the URL path yourself:

```golang
func HandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    segments := strings.Split(request.URL.Path, "/")
    // If path is /events/id, then segments[2] will have the id
}
```

Request.URL.Path is already URL decoded, so if your parameters may contain slashes use [Request.RequestURI](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.RequestURI) and [url.PathUnescape](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#PathUnescape) instead:

```golang
segments := strings.Split(r.RequestURI, "/")
for i := range segments {
    var err error
    segments[i], err = url.PathUnescape(segments[i])
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the slice of the string starting after `/events/`:

```
func eventHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.URL.Path[len("/events/"):]
    w.Write([]byte("The ID is " + id))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/events/", eventHandler)
}
```